# Why don't these samples come from a normal distribution?

Tags: statistics, random-variables, normal-distribution, sampling, python

I have two sets of 1000 $L_2$-normalized vectors (each being 512 elements long). I compute the similarities of each vector from one set with each vector in the other set using the inner product, which yields  a total of 1.000.000 similarity-computations between vectors. When i construct a histogram out of the resulting similarities i get the following image:

[image]

which looks very much like a normal distribution to me. When i manually construct a normal-distribution with $\mu$ and $\sigma$ of the empirical data i get the following plot:

```
from scipy import stats

mu = similarities.mean()
variance = similarities.var()
sigma = similarities.std()

x = np.linspace(mu - 5*sigma, mu + 5*sigma, 100)

sns.histplot(without_diag, stat='density');
plt.plot(x, stats.norm.pdf(x, mu, sigma), 'r', alpha=0.6);
```

[image]

Which seems to fit just fine. I used numpy to perform the computation and seaborn to plot the histogram. I used [`scipy.stats.normaltest`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.normaltest.html) to test, if the samples come from a normal-distribution. Result:

```
>>> k2, p = stats.normaltest(without_diag)
>>> print(p)
3.2035057152116813e-221
```

I read somewhere, that $p$ should be below $0.05$ in order to reject the null-hypothesis, that the data was sampled from a normal-distribution and $3\times 10^{-221}$ seems very much to be below that border. Does it have to do with the number of samples? Is there a name for this kind of distribution?

**EDIT:**

Here is the normal probability-plot suggested in the answer by @heropup:

[image]

Comment: You know that they don't come from a normal? I don't understand.

Comment: Well, i know it because the `normaltest` failed!

Comment: Oh ok. I got it the other way around.

Comment: Perhaps student's then?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! I'm searching for a way in Python to evaluate that

Comment: We do not know how you constructed your vectors or your similarity-computations, but a likely reason is that the theoretical distribution is not quite normal and $1$ million examples is more than enough to reveal this.

Comment: Thanks @Henry for the reply. I added a plot showing the normal distribution for the empirical data! In my eyes it fits just fine! I still can't see, where i'm wrong here!

Comment: Describe the entire procedure. What is your similarity measure? How are those vectors drawn? etc...

Comment: Hi @d.k.o. and thanks for the request. I added some information at the start of the question. Does this help you? If not, could you tell me which information is missing?

Comment: Your final chart shows a clear deviation from normality in the right tail which seems slightly heavier than a normal distribution.  Your sample size is big enough to reveal this in the test

Comment: Thanks! This means i could search for right-tail-heavy distributions and test which one fits best, am i right with this assumption? Can you suggest a distribution i should try?

Comment: You have an empirical distribution from your sample which you could use directly.  It is almost but not quite normally distributed.  What do you want to use it for?

Comment: I would like to make statements about the probability of an outlier (e.g. "How probable is it to retain a similarity of 0.8 for the given distribution?")

Answer (score 1):

Rather than plotting a histogram, it may be more informative to create a [normal probability plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_probability_plot).  This may show deviations for normality that might be hidden in a histogram; e.g. tails too heavy or sparse.

A caveat regarding statistical tests of non-normality is that, like many statistical tests, the power to reject becomes greater as the sample size increases.  With $n = 10^6$ this means that even a small deviation from normality may be detected by such a test.

That said, the resulting $p$-value you obtained does suggest deviation from normality; however, whether the extent of such deviation is meaningful--i.e., "effect size" as it pertains to measures of goodness-of-fit--is a separate question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I added the normal probability-plot to the original question, however. It deviates pretty strongly above the 3rd quantile. However, i can't really make sense of that, since i've never worked with this kind of plot. Can you explain, what the deviation actually means? Also, how can i find the distribution that fits my data best?

Comment: @TimHilt This plot suggests that the right tail of your data is very slightly heavier than what you would expect if the data were truly normally distributed.  This is why your hypothesis test rejected the null.  The fact that this deviation is still so small despite the large sample size means that your overall fit is actually quite good.

Comment: Many thanks! This actually helps a lot.